# Very slow scrolling performance, using a wide canvas with a scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, canvas, scrollviewer

I have a C# WPF application with a Canvas. The Canvas is wider then the screen, so I use a ScrollViewer on the Canvas. And everything is working fine.

Here comes the problem:
With a much wider Canvas (width=44655), the performance of the scrollviewer is really slow. Changing the scrollposition takes a couple of seconds.
How can I increase the performance for this wide Canvas?

The Canvas I use = 44655 x 969
The width of the ScrollViewer = 1488

I've tried to place the children elements (total of 602 children elements) of the Canvas in one Bitmap, and place this one Bitmap on the same Canvas (after first removing all the children elements). This improves the performance big-time and it works as needed. But the memory-usage is huge, causing Out-Of-Memory exceptions many times. (I've also written the Bitmap as PNG to a file and this results in a file of 6MB, with 44655x969 pixels).

Is there another way to increase the scroll-performance with the Canvas? Or is there a way to reduce the memory use with the following code.

This is the code for making Bitmap from the Canvas and placing this Bitmap on the Canvas again:

```cs
double cnvsW = Cnvs.Width;
double cnvsH = realCnvsHeight;
if (double.IsNaN(cnvsW))
    cnvsW = 0;
Size size = new Size(cnvsW, cnvsH);
    // Measure and arrange the Canvas
Cnvs.Measure(size);
Cnvs.Arrange(new Rect(size));

// Create a render bitmap and push the canvas to it
RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);//.Pbgra32);
renderBitmap.Render(Cnvs);

// Save to bitmap opbject
PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Interlace = PngInterlaceOption.Off;
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
encoder.Save(stream);

System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(stream);

// Save to file for debugging
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("testCanvas.png", stream.ToArray());

// Now place the bitmap to the canvas on the screen
Cnvs.Children.Clear();
IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

try
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Image image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
    image.Source = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    Canvas.SetTop(image, 0);
    Cnvs.Children.Add(image);
    Cnvs.Width = size.Width;
}
finally
{
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}
```

Comment: Are you compiled for 64 bit?  I had similar out of memory issues hen I was compiled with x86 mode.  Changing the mode helped.  Also spent time fixing memory leaks.

Comment: No, compiled with x86 mode. The application also needs to run on 32-bit machines. So sadly I'm stuck with the x86 mode......

Comment: x86 does not mean 32 bit mode.  Did you try running in 32 bit mode without x86?

Comment: The whole idea of "let's use big enough Canvas, put it into Scrollviewer and let WPF do the rest" is flawed. Not sure what exactly you doing: graph or CAD, but old good bitmap of current window size maximum (result of render) with all zoom/positioning/hit tests done in logic is the right way. Or use a proper game engine (if it's a game).

Comment: The big Canvas with ScrollViewer was actual not the first need in the application. During time the application expended with new functionality. I'm viewing graph data of a certain time-frame. Now (for new functions) I need to expand this timeframe. There is a lot of drawing done, so I would prefer to keep the Canvas drawing the same, but be able to present it in the right way.

Comment: Not sure if this will suit you but building a writeablebitmap is very fast. I build a fairly large one for several purposes and it takes about 26ms on an i5 for 1165 *805 px